# How to retrieve a value from API in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json, rest

I want to get the value from the API, here on each method onGetAPI, onGetCluster and so on I am printing the entire json object. The output json object is - http://json-parser.com/82ce228b/1

But in the json object I have highlighted 2 values first one is cluster id and the other is analysis id. I want to print these values separately and store in a variable. I want to parse out those values from href and print them separately.[image]

```js
import React from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

class MTS extends React.Component {


    onGetAPI=()=>{
        var _self = this;
        axios.get('http://127.0.0.1/api/v1/version')
        .then(response =>
        {
            this.setState({ msgStatus : response.status, strStatusText : response.statusText }) //  console.log(this.msgStatus) ;
            return response.json();
         })
        //.then(data => this.setState({ version : data })
        .then(function(json) {
            console.log(json);
            _self.receiveData(json);
          }  );     
    }

    onGetClusters=()=>{
        <label>Cluster ID <input style={{backgroundColor: "lightgray"}} type = "textarea" ref ="input"></input></label>

        var _self = this;
        axios.get('http://127.0.0.1/api/v1/clusters')
        .then(response =>
        {
            this.setState({ msgStatus : response.status , strStatusText : response.statusText}) //  console.log(this.msgStatus) ;
            return response.json();
          })
        //.then(data => this.setState({ clusters : data })
        .then(function(json) {
            console.log(json);
            _self.receiveData(json);
            
          }  );
    }
 
      receiveData(data) {
         this.setState({data});
      }

    onGetClustersID=()=>{
        var _self1 = this;
        let clusterinfo = this.refs.input.value;
        let clusterinfo1 =JSON.parse(clusterinfo);
        console.log(clusterinfo);

        axios.get(' http://127.0.0.1/api/v1/clusters/'+ clusterinfo)
        .then(response =>
            {
                this.setState({ msgStatus : response.status, strStatusText : response.statusText }) //  console.log(this.msgStatus) ;
                return response.json();
             })
            //.then(data => this.setState({ clusters : data })
            .then(function(json) {
                console.log(json);
                _self1.receiveData(json);
                console.log(clusterinfo1);
              }  );
    }



    render(){
        

        return (
            
          <div style={{backgroundColor: "lightblue"}}>
  
              
  
              <h1 style={{backgroundColor: "lightblue",color: "Darkblue",textAlign : "center"}}> MTS GRAPH </h1>
  
  
              <h2>1. Get the API version <button style={{backgroundColor: "lightgreen"}} onClick = {this.onGetAPI}>GET - API Version</button></h2> 
  
              <h2>2.a. Get the Clusters  <button style={{backgroundColor: "lightgreen"}} onClick = {this.onGetClusters}>GET - Cluster</button></h2>
             
              <h2>2.b. Get the Clusters ID <button style={{backgroundColor: "lightgreen"}} onClick = {this.onGetClustersID}>GET - Cluster ID</button></h2>  
              <p>
                  <label>Cluster ID <input style={{backgroundColor: "lightgray"}} type = "textarea" ref ="input"></input></label>
              </p>                   
  
              <h2>3.a. Get AnalysisUnit ID <button style={{backgroundColor: "lightgreen"}} onClick = {this.onGetAnalysisUnitID}>GET - AnalysisUnit ID</button></h2>  
              <p>
                  <label>Cluster ID <input style={{backgroundColor: "lightgray"}} type = "textarea" ref ="input1"></input></label>
                  <label>AnalysisUnit ID <input style={{backgroundColor: "lightgray"}} type = "textarea" ref ="input2"></input></label>
              </p>

              <h5> ******************************************************************************************</h5>
            
            <h4>Response status : {this.state.msgStatus} {this.state.strStatusText}</h4>
            <h4> Output :  {JSON.stringify(this.state.data)}</h4>  

            <h5> ******************************************************************************************</h5>

           
        </div>

        
      ) 
    }
}

export default MTS;
```

Comment: where is receiveData ? Can you add it up?

Comment: receiveData(data) {
        this.setState({data});
    }

Answer (score 1):

If you are certain that the values will always be in their given position. You can do something like

```
const clusterId = href.split('/')[5]
const analysisId = href.split('/')[7]
```

Comment: Yes values will always be in that position.

Answer (score 1):

If you know what's the keyword that precedes your ID:

```
const getValue = (string, id) => {
    const stringArray = string.split("/");
    const index = stringArray.indexOf(id);
    return stringArray[index + 1];
}

clusterId = getValue(json[0].analysisUnits.links[0].href, "clusters");
analysisId = getValue(json[0].links[0].href, "aus");
```

Comment: Whether this could be changed to key-value pair such that, if there is new cluster the new cluster should stored and added.